# Dynamically add Yii form elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

I have a problem integrating Yii and jQuery when trying to dynamically add fields generated by Yii to my form.
Namely, statically I use this code to have a dropdownlist on my form:

```
echo $form->label($model,Yii::t('candidates', 'Contact type'));
$options = CHtml::listData(HrpContactTypes::model()->findAll(),'id','type');
 $ct = array();
 $b=1;
for($i=0;$i<=count($options)-1;$i++) {
    $ct[$b] = Yii::t('candidates', $options[$b]);
    $b++;
}
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'contact_type_id',$ct,array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

and I use this code to have a text-input on my form:

```
echo $form->label($model,Yii::t('candidates', 'Contact')); ?>
echo $form->textField($model,'contact', array('required'=>'required', 'class'=>'form-control' ));
```

Then, I use this code to dynamically add elements to my form:

```
$('#addContact').click(function() {
        $('#row').append(
            '<br><div class="col-md-6">contact type</div><div class="col-md-6">contact</div>'
            );
        return false;
    });
```

MY QUESTION IS: HOW TO DYNAMICALLY ADD YII DROPDOWNLIST AND YII TEXT-INPUT WITH THE HELP OF JQUERY?

Answer (score 0):

At first please pay attention on coding.

1. Second parameter of **[CActiveForm::label()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#label-detail)** must be attribute, and translate it you must in your model class (overriding method [attributeLabels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#attributeLabels-detail)), not in form:

   ```
   public functions attributeLabels() {
       return array(
           'candidates' => Yii::t('candidates', 'Contact type'),
           ATTRUBUTE_NAME => ATTRIBUTE_LABEL
       );
   }
   ```
2. Read about [loops in php](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm). Instead of declaring additional varaible `$b` you can use loop varaible `$i`, also you get values from `$optios` starting from 1, so your last element of `$ct` always `null`, I think you want to write this:

   ```
   $options = CHtml::listData(HrpContactTypes::model()->findAll(),'id','type');
   $ct = array();
   for($i=0; $i<count($options); $i++) {
       $ct[$i+1] = Yii::t('candidates', $options[$i]);
   }
   ```

Thanks.